# Cannot instantiate abstract class Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\AbstractView

Tags: magento-2.1, fatal-error, product-page

After `Magento 2.1 compilation` i have this error when I try to open product page in the frontend (in the backend it work):
in

```
/var/www/vhosts/mywebsite/httpdocs/mywebsitemarketplace/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:93
Stack trace: #0
/var/www/vhosts/mywebsite/httpdocs/mywebsitemarketplace/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(88):
Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Catalog...',
Array)
#1/var/www/vhosts/mywebsite/httpdocs/mywebsitemarketplace/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(130):
Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Magento\\Catalog...')
#2 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite/httpdocs/mywebsitemarketplace/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(67):
Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->get('Magento\\Catalog...')
#3 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite/httpdocs/mywebsitemarketplace/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(57):
Magento\Framework\Objec in
/var/www/vhosts/mywebsite/httpdocs/mywebsitemarketplace/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php
on line 93
```

Answer (score 10):

The following command will helps you.
Please Run Upgrade Command:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Comment: I also faced the same issue but in my case setup upgrade did not work, I have to switch on production mode then again developer mode and it worked.